# Comparison operator "==" in PHP confusion

Tags: php

In PHP,

```
null==0
0=="0"
```

If you combine these two, you would expect:

```
null=="0"
```

But this is not true.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: PHP is not logical. `null == (boolean) '0'` is `true` again…

Comment: The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is the only possible value of type null.

A variable is considered to be null if:

it has been assigned the constant NULL.

it has not been set to any value yet.

it has been unset().

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: and 0 == "0" is not correct. 0 is an integer and "0" is a string :)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/569101)

Comment: [PHP comparison tables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) - just use this instead of looking for logical explanations.

Comment: @OctoD: seems like you havn't understood what this question is about. you're right that a number isn't the same as a string, but since PHP only has weak types those comparisions can give confusing results. take a look at this: http://codepad.org/ARVz5Q7v (you see, `0 == "0"` is `true` in PHP)

Comment: maybe you should rather use `===` if you want a logical, transitive equation operator.

Comment: @oezi sorry for the mistake ^^ have you tried with === ? it should checks type and equality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that because PHP is not strict in its typing it is often casting your variables to other types depending on the comparison or operation needed. In the case of null==0 it is telling you that both null and integer 0 are considered false.

In the case of null == "0" it is checking if the string "0" is empty which it is not. Comparing integer 0 with string "0" type cases "0" to an int for comparison in which case they are equal.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

In the first case:

```
null==0
```

`null` evaluates to `false` , same as `0` which evaluates to `false`, so both are `false` and so the comparison returns `true`.

In second case:

```
0=="0"
```

here you are comparing two variables of different type, one is numerical and other string, because you are not using the [**===**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator, PHP cast one of them to the other type so **0** casted to string equals **"0"** which so they are the same, if it's **"0"** which is casted to number also casts to **0** so its the same as the other value, and so this comparison returns true.

In third case:

```
null=="0"
```

here's the same situation, both are different types so PHP cast one of them to the type of the other, but if you cast null to string the result is **"null"** which is not equal to **"0"**, so that's the reason is not true that comparison.

Comment: the third case explanation cannot be true, because null=="" (and "null" != ""). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`==` checks equality

`===` checks equality **AND** type (we also say it is "identical")

Therefore, since PHP does not have strong type hinting, it is automatically casted to the best suited type.

`null === 0` is `false` while `null == 0` is true because `0` or `'0'` are considered as null value as well as `false`. An empty value `null == ''` will return `true` too.

That's how PHP works.

A best practice is to always check for type using the `===` operator (and its negative equivalent, `!==` and use only the other in special cases).