# How to remember multiple selected options in a select-tag?

Tags: php

I have a `<select>` with multiple allowed choices at the same time. I want to keep ALL selected values after a form submission. How to do this?

I tried the followig, but this only works for ONE option...

```
<select multiple name="example" method="POST" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
  <option value="optA" <?php if ($_POST['example'] === "optA"){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Option A</option>
  <option value="optB" <?php if ($_POST['example'] === "optB"){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Option B</option>
</select>
```

Expectedly the following always returns the latest selected option:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['example'])){echo $_POST["example"];} ?>
```

So how can i achieve my goal? Many thx in advance! :)

Comment: why using "===" ? you should use "=="

Comment: try doing `print_r($_POST['example'])` instead of echo

Comment: change `name="example" ` to `name="example[]" ` and do `print_r($_POST['example])`.

Comment: @FareedMN because it is a good practice, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474019/comparison-operator-in-php-confusion/12474208#12474208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array as the POST variable, like this:

```
<select multiple name="example[]">
  // options
</select>
```

And retrieve them like so:

```
print_r($_POST['example']);
```

I would suggest storing your option values and names in an array as well, so it's easier to handle:

```
$options = array(
  array(
    'value' => 0,
    'name'  => 'A'
  ),
  array(
    'value' => 1,
    'name'  => 'B'
  ),
  array(
    'value' => 2,
    'name'  => 'C'
  ),
  array(
    'value' => 3,
    'name'  => 'D'
  )
);
```

Then just simply create your select options, using a `foreach` loop, and check if the current option is in your post variable:

```
<select multiple name="example[]">
  <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>"<?php echo (isset($_POST['example']) && in_array($option['value'], $_POST['example'])) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $option['name']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this works nicely! I changed the php to `<?php if (in_array("optA", $_POST["example"])){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>`. Do you think that's the best way to do it?